# Modbus TCP with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, modbus

I am trying to communicate with Modbus via TCP. I want to use this type of code without a library.

The code is run like this :

```
 sudo python3 modbus_master.py
```

When I run the program with this code then I see my Modbus connection defined in Wireshark. I am also using slave Modbus programs (more than one) but there is no connection with my master.

**What am I doing wrong in the following code?**

```
#!/usr/bin/python3           
# This is client.py file

import socket
import struct
import time

# Create a TCP/IP socket
TCP_IP = '192.168.0.107'
TCP_PORT = 502
BUFFER_SIZE = 39
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.connect((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))

try:

    unitId = 16
    functionCode = 5
    print("\n,Switching plug on")
    coilId = 1
    req = struct.pack('12B', 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x06, int(unitId), int(functionCode), 0x00, int(coilId),
                      0xff,
                      0x00)
    sock.send(req)
    print("TX: (%s)" % req)


    time.sleep(2)

finally:
    print('\nCLOSING SOCKET')
    sock.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is in *IP* or *Port* with the firewall.

So if your codes run in the same machine, you can use `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` IP instead of machine IP.

---

[**NOTE**]:

If your OS is ***nix** system based, and you have the `ufw` firewall, doing the following command:

```
$ sudo ufw disable
```